# Enterprise app is not installed in some iPads over the air

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-provisioning, ota

I have a ipa file which has build using Enterprise inhouse provisioning profile. We use OTA method to install that app in to our clients ipads. But App is not installed in to some ipads. Now we  were able to recreate issue using two ipads. I have ipad4 and ipad2. Both connected to same wifi network and both have iOS 7.0.6. Then I tried to download the app using OTA. It installed in the ipad4 successfully but not installed in ipad2. It gives the "Unable to download the App" error message. Then I connect that to my mac and check the device's console. It has following messages.

```
iPad itunesstored[561] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing placeholder for com.MyCompany.MyApp
iPad installd[536] <Notice>: 0x39d000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/1749989453537340485.app" requested by itunesstored
iPad installd[536] <Notice>: 0x39d000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.MyCompany.MyApp
iPad installd[536] <Notice>: 0x39d000 install_application: Installing placeholder
iPad installd[536] <Notice>: 0x39d000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.11s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.13s
iPad itunesstored[561] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: com.MyCompany.MyApp (Placeholder) withPhase:0
iPad lsd[533] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Waiting; fractionCompleted=0.000000> to 0
iPad com.apple.StreamingUnzipService[563] <Warning>: -[StreamingUnzipState finishStream]:423: Finishing an incomplete stream! This stream will not be resumable.
iPad SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: Killing com.MyCompany.MyApp for app installation
iPad itunesstored[561] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder LSApplicationProxy: com.MyCompany.MyApp (Placeholder)
iPad itunesstored[561] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: com.MyCompany.MyApp (Placeholder) withPhase:1
iPad lsd[533] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Active; fractionCompleted=0.600000> to 1
iPad installd[536] <Notice>: 0x39d000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/1749989453537340485/7080414486808559068" requested by itunesstored
iPad installd[536] <Error>: 0x39d000 peruse_package: App info dict loaded from "/var/tmp/install_staging.oyOT8C/7080414486808559068.app" did not have bundle identifier
iPad installd[536] <Error>: 0x39d000 stage_package: Could not peruse package at /var/tmp/install_staging.oyOT8C/7080414486808559068.app
iPad installd[536] <Error>: 0x39d000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Could not stage the package
iPad itunesstored[561] <Error>: 0x3b1000 MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices: failed with -1
iPad installd[536] <Error>: 0x39d000 handle_install_for_ls: API failed
iPad itunesstored[561] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
iPad lsd[533] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app com.MyCompany.MyApp
iPad itunesstored[561] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.MyCompany.MyApp.Installing - <NSProgress: phase=Installing; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=0.000000> called, removing progress from cache
iPad backboardd[29] <Warning>: Chrome[582]: Could not stat /private/var/mobile/Applications/95F58263-C6D2-4105-A4D8-62DE122E2878/tmp/etilqs_td6dxKTMWgjL7qB: No such file or directory
iPad lsd[533] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app com.MyCompany.MyApp
iPad itunesstored[561] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: com.MyCompany.MyApp.Loading - <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=1.000000> called, removing progress from cache
```

Can some one help me to sort this out.

Comment: probably reason is you added wrong UDID or you forget to add udid for device that you trying to install.

Comment: No.. It has used inhouse provisioning profile. So no need of adding UDID of that device right?

Comment: Hi @nath did you get any solution? I am also facing same issue. Thanks