# ios - Unable to download application but app installed correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I distribute my iOS App from HTTP server as enterprise  distribution. When a user download App directly from web browser, the  app installed correctly and no errors occur.

On the other hand, the app have a process for automatic updates.  When user start application if a new version of the application on the  server, be show a alert for starting download. If user accept, it begins  download. During the installation process, the following message is  displayed:

```
"Unable to download application"
```

but the application has been installed correctly. I use this code for download app:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:serverUrlDownload];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

This occurs when user used iPhone 5s.

Showed following error in log:

```
<Warning>: Download url: itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://server_update/ios/IOS_WF.plist
<Warning>: LaunchServices: installing placeholder for app10.IOS-WF
<Notice>: 0x1005a4000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/-6609911948116439539.app" requested by itunesstored
<Notice>: 0x1005a4000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app app10.IOS-WF
<Notice>: 0x1005a4000 install_application: Installing parallel placeholder
<Notice>: 0x1005a4000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.00s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.12s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.12s
<Warning>: No se ha obtenido ningún flujo
<Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: app10.IOS-WF (Placeholder) withPhase:0
<Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app app10.IOS-WF
<Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: app10.IOS-WF.Loading - <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=1.000000> called, removing progress from cache
```

Reproduce Issue in iPhone 5s.

I couldn't reproduce error in iPhone 4s.

Any idea? Can be a problem of server configuration?

Comment: Same unanswered question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139506/enterprise-app-is-not-installed-in-some-ipads-over-the-air)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not already done so, you might want to try to supply the app via https instead of http.

As of iOS 7.1, https is required for at least the manifest file, although there are some reports saying http would still work anyway.

The whole story with https being required came as a surprise to most devs and appears to have hickup at the same time. I can well imagine differences of the implementation of the process across different devices due to different OS builds, especially since there's 32 and 64 bit architectures now.

This is a wild guess, but it won't hurt to try. If you don't have a SSL capable server at hand, you might want to use dropbox as workaround, as has been explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20736713/416600).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've already tested with a https server using a ssl certificate generated by me and the result is the same, shown alert with error but app is installed. For other hand, If I use a http or https dropbox server for distribute app, it download and install satisfactorily and not showing any error. The problem is that I can not use dropbox server for distribute production app.

Comment: It appears like in the case of a self-signed certificate you need to make it a trusted profile via iPhone configurator. Please see the comments to this answer, especially those of Niralp and Monobono: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20276908/416600

Comment: Yes, with the self-signed certificate of distribution server SSL I made a trusted profile via iPhone Utility Configuration and installed it on device but the problem persist. The self-signed certificate is not from a AC recognized, can be the problem?

Comment: I suppose so - since it does work via dropbox, which provides a chain of trust without gaps, I think it is safe to assume that the lack thereof causes the problem with your server / self-signed cert. You can create your own private CA though, since you're targeting internal use (and security apparently was a non-issue prior to iOS 7.1 to you) this should be sufficient. Monobono, whose comment I mentioned, apparently solved the issue this way...

Comment: I already did what said Monobeno but I believe that my problem is other (is posible that may be related with self-certificate CA) because app is downloaded and installed on device but shown the alert who said "Unable to download app". This doesn't always happen, if I run app on iPhone 4s alert error not shown. On iPhone 5s error occurs. Version iOS is the same, 7.0.6.